# How do I store a custom collection of data in memory during run time?

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to collect some data and temporarily store it in memory and then write it to a file.
At first I thought I could just use a Dictionary and made it all work, but when I finnsihed, I realized I need a third element in there, so Dictionarys is of no use I guess.

The three elements would be something like string name, bool asked, DateTime today.

When the function starts, I need to read a file where these elements are stored one per line, separated with a pipe.
As I am going through the function, I will need to add items if a condition evaluates to false in a foreach loop, or remove if the condition is true.
When the function is completed, I need to erase the file, and dump the contents of the array back to the file.

THe meaning would be like checking if John Doe has been asked if his task is completed yet and XX days has passed since he was last asked.
If XX days has passed, remove his record from the array, ask him again, and add new record to the array with todays date. (or simply, changed date in the array and ask again).
Then dump the contents of the array to the file so we can go through it again tomorrow.

I have never worked with arrays before though, so I have absolutely no clue of how to do this.. and when I search google I find a lot of examples, but none that really makes sense to me.

Could any of you let me know how you would proceed with this, as I am completely clueless.

Comment: What's the key value from `name` `asked` and `today` ?

Comment: asawyer: Well, when I thought of the directory the KeyValuePair would be string name, key datetime.

Nya: Sorry, I couldn't come to think of a better title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a more complete example, consider the following:

```
public class SurveyData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Asked { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

private Dictionary<string, SurveyData>() SurveyInfo = new Dictionary<string, SurveyData>();

public function LoadData()
{
    // Code to read from disk omitted for brevity. Assume you've parsed
    // the line into 3 variables: name, asked, date.

    var item = new SurveyData()
        {
           Name = name,
           Asked = asked,
           Date = date
        };

    this.SurveyInfo.Add(item.Name, item);
}
```

With this sample, you're still using a Dictionary, so you can search by name. But the item data is all stored in the values. So you can do the following:

```
public function UpdateIfAsked(string name)
{
    var item = this.SurveyInfo[name];
    if (item != null)
    {
        // Update the itme or remove it.
        if (item.Asked && item.Date < DateTime.Today)
        {
            SurveyInfo.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

PS. This gets much easier with LINQ, but that's probably a bit advanced for ya at this point.

Comment: Hmm.. I get completely stuck here and have tried to solve it, but seem not able to.
If the name is not fint in the dictionary, I get stuck at:
`var item = this.SurveyInfo[name];`

Iv'e been trying to check if the name is in the dictionary by first using `if(SurveyInfo.ContainsKey(name)){ var check = this.SurveyCheck[name];}` but when I do that, the compiler complains about check not existing in the current contect.
And as far as I understand, I have to initialize the check var directly, I can't just set it to null first and fill it up if the name is found in the dictionary.

Comment: Never mind, I was just thinking wrong.
I just needed to move everything that should be done inside the said if statement, and not leave the statement alone and the go check if item was null or not. :)

Answer (score 6):

You should make yourself an object, something like...

```
class yourObject
{
    string name { get; set; }
    bool asked { get; set; }
    DateTime date { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can just make a List of them to store multiple ones in memory.

```
List<yourObject> myObjects = new List<yourObject>();

yourObject myObject = new yourObject();

yourObject.name = "Bob";
yourObject.asked = true;
yourObject.date = DateTime.Today;

myObjects.Add(yourObject);
```

etc... do that in a loop or do some data binding from your data source to fill it up.

Writing to a file is another animal, try searching Google for C# how to write data to a file ([here's a result from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx)). What you will need to do is determine how you want it to be stored though, because this will determine how you will read it back later. Can you use a database table instead?

Answer (score 2):

Make an object with these 3 properties and then List of these objects, like:

```
       class MyClass
       {
           string name;
           bool asked;
           DateTime date;
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a class to represent the data you work with:

```
class PersonTask
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public bool Asked {get;set;}
    public DateTime Time {get;set;}
}
```

Now you can use a `List<PersonTask>` to store the data you need, or if you need to look up people by name, a `Dictionary<string,PersonTask>`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to use an array..

Just create an object like this:

```
public class RowItem
{
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public bool Asked{ get; set; }
        public DateTime Date{ get; set; }
}
```

and then use an IList

```
IList<RowItem> rows = new List<RowItem>();
```

Comment: wow! while i was writing my answer 4 people wrote the same answer

Comment: Because an array was the only thing I could think of..
Just as LINQ would be to advanced for me, as Mike points out.. a lot other things are too.

I'm faaaaar from a good programmer..   just trying things out to make things easier for me :)